# libxml error handler with OOP

Tags: php, oop, error-handling, libxml2

I need catch libxml errors. But I want to use my class for this. I know about `libxml_get_errors` and other function. But I need something like `libxml_set_erroc_class("myclass")` and in all case for error will call my class. I don't want in each case after use `$dom->load(...)` create some construction like `foreach(libxml_get_errors as $error) {....}`. Can you help me?

Comment: Am not sure why you want to do this but `libxml_get_errors()` return array of `LibXMLError` Object ... may be  with more information and code .. i can help

Comment: ok. I have classes for dom - Builder and Parser, have calss Validator for validate xml via xsd. How I can implements my own error handler for this classes. And I need use Exception class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`libxml errors` are mostly generated when reading or writing `xml` document because automatic validation is done.

So this is where you should concentrate and you don't need to overwrite the `set_error_handler` .. Here is a prove of concept

Use Internal Errors

```
libxml_use_internal_errors ( true );
```

Sample XML

```
$xmlstr = <<< XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<movies>
 <movie>
  <titles>PHP: Behind the Parser</title>
 </movie>
</movies>
XML;

echo "<pre>" ;
```

I guess this is an example of the kind of what you want to achieve

```
try {
    $loader = new XmlLoader ( $xmlstr );
} catch ( XmlException $e ) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

XMLLoader Class

```
class XmlLoader {
    private $xml;
    private $doc;
    function __construct($xmlstr) {
        $doc = simplexml_load_string ( $xmlstr );

        if (! $doc) {
            throw new XmlException ( libxml_get_errors () );
        }
    }
}
```

XmlException Class

```
class XmlException extends Exception {

    private $errorMessage = "";
    function __construct(Array $errors) {

        $x = 0;
        foreach ( $errors as $error ) {
            if ($error instanceof LibXMLError) {
                $this->parseError ( $error );
                $x ++;
            }
        }
        if ($x > 0) {
            parent::__construct ( $this->errorMessage );
        } else {
            parent::__construct ( "Unknown Error XmlException" );
        }
    }

    function parseError(LibXMLError $error) {
        switch ($error->level) {
            case LIBXML_ERR_WARNING :
                $this->errorMessage .= "Warning $error->code: ";
                break;
            case LIBXML_ERR_ERROR :
                $this->errorMessage .= "Error $error->code: ";
                break;
            case LIBXML_ERR_FATAL :
                $this->errorMessage .= "Fatal Error $error->code: ";
                break;
        }

        $this->errorMessage .= trim ( $error->message ) . "\n  Line: $error->line" . "\n  Column: $error->column";

        if ($error->file) {
            $this->errorMessage .= "\n  File: $error->file";
        }
    }

}
```

Sample Output

```
Fatal Error 76: Opening and ending tag mismatch: titles line 4 and title
  Line: 4
  Column: 46
```

I hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: Cool .. am glad i was able to help .... don't forget to accept if it solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

**edit** (confused exceptions with errors):

1. Use [set_exception_handler](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) to catch global exceptions.
2. Have your code throw these exceptions in cases like `$dom->load()`. Because `libxml` doesn't seem to throw exceptions on its own, your other option is to create a wrapper around it, use the wrapper in your code and have it check `libxml` for errors and throw them in necessary cases.
3. Handle the exceptions inside "myclass".

Be wary though that the `set_exception_handler` will be catching **all** your exceptions.

Here's an example of what you could do:

```
//inheritance example (composition, though, would be better)
class MyDOMWrapper extends DOMDocument{
    public function load($filename, $options = 0){
        $bool = parent::load($filename, $options);
        if (!$bool){
            throw new MyDOMException('Shit happens. Feeling lucky.', 777);
        }
    }
}
class MyDOMException extends DOMException{
    public $libxml;

    public function __construct($message, $code){
        parent::__construct($message, $code);
        $this->libxml = libxml_get_errors();
    }
}
class MyDOMExceptionHandler{
    public static function handle($e){
        //handle exception globally
    }
}
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
set_exception_handler(array('MyDOMErrorHandler', 'handle'));

//global exception handler
$myDom = new MyDOMWrapper();
$myDom->load('main.xml');

//when special handling is necessary
try {
    $myDom = new MyDOMWrapper();
    $myDom->load('main.xml');
} catch (MyDOMException $e) {   
    //handle or
    throw $e; //rethrow
}
```

Comment: can you give me example of wrapper. Example : I use dom operation vary often in my code and I don't want after each opearation use construction foreach (libxml_get_errors as $error) {...}. I can move this code to some function and call it. But I don't call it after each operation with dom. I want something error_handler : I declarate my clss for proccess error, add it to libxml in ONE place and don't care that some othet will be edited classes for dom and forget add call function for catching error or code structure which I wrote above

Answer (score 1):

There is no facility to do this directly. Your options would be:

1. extend the PHP class that uses libxml and wrap your custom error handling logic around the stock implementation (not that good), or
2. write your own class that aggregates an instance of that PHP class and create your own public interface around it (better, because you are in control of the public interface and you don't risk problems if the PHP class is extended in the future), or
3. replace the global error handler for the duration of your parsing and restore it afterwards (not as powerful, may be problematic if your code calls into other code, however easier to do)

Solutions 1 and 2 have the advantage that they do not modify the behavior of any other code in your application no matter what.